# How to set page number 2 as start page for roman / arabic numbers?

Tags: arabic, page, roman, number

I am writing my master thesis on Latex. I want page number 2 to start with the roman number i. How do I do this? Now page nr 2 starts with ii (instead of i). The front page I have wiped out, using \thispagestyle{empty}.

Comment: Somewhere on that page (the one you want to be `i`), `setcounter{page}{0}`.